# HTTPS через HTTP прокси

Tags: c++, http, https, proxy

Написал простой http прокси.
Но встал вопрос, как быть с https?
Я пробовал просто пересылать данные между сокетом браузера и сокетом к серверу который я создал, но не получилось с этого ничего.
Подскажите, где я не правильно делаю?

```
if(Port[0]==':')
{
    char FF[]="HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established";
    send(output,FF,strlen(FF),0);
    closesocket(requestSock);
    return "";
    send(requestSock,request,strlen(request),0);


    while(TRUE)
    {
        DWORD ul;
        //ioctlsocket(requestSock, FIONREAD, &ul);
        //if(ul > 0)
        {
        nRead=recv(requestSock,proxyRecvBuf.buf,1,0);
        if(nRead == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            return"";
        }
        if(nRead>0)
        {
            memcpy(sendBuf,buf,bufferSize);
            send(output,sendBuf,nRead,0);
        }
        }
        //ioctlsocket(output, FIONREAD, &ul);
        //if(ul > 0)
        {
        nRead=recv(output,proxyRecvBuf.buf,1,0);
        if(nRead == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            return"";
        }
        if(nRead>0)
        {
            memcpy(sendBuf,buf,bufferSize);
            send(requestSock,sendBuf,nRead,0);
        }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Надо использовать метод CONNECT, к вышестоящему прокси, если он есть. И с клиентом: если он подключается напрямую как к прокси серверу, он тоже использует метод CONNECT, если это 'прозрачный прокси' то надо отлавливать destination пакета, или парсить в нем TLS SNI, и брать адрес сервера оттуда. Это только первый этап. В общем хороший прокси это не простая задача.

Comment: Т.е. просто так нельзя соединить два сокета?"отлавливать destination пакета," - можно поподробней?

Comment: Определитель сперва со схемой, кто за чем стоит, и destination это назначение TCP пакета в данном контексте.

Comment: И переведённый вами код не полный, и в любом случае не работоспособный, это просто набор функций в произвольном порядке.